# HTTPService get sent POST body on FaultEvent

Tags: actionscript-3, httpservice

Is it possible to get at the data that I sent via a HTTPService Send('I want to get at this data') method when a FaultEvent is raised? Either by looking at the global HTTPService variable or at the FaultEvent object.

Comment: So you can add an actual answer below (instead of editing the question), mark your question as answered, and thus help other people when they face the same problem.

Comment: I can't see anywhere to mark my question as answered. :-/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do I work these things out just after I've asked a question on here :)

```
  private function httpFault(e:FaultEvent):void {       
     var sentXML:XML = XML(e.token.message.body);       
  }
```